# Pandas dataframe export to excel causes TypeError

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to export a dataframe from pandas to excel doing so :

```
writer = pd.io.excel.ExcelWriter(args.out_file, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'constant_memory': True})
summary_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='summary', na_rep='NA', index=False)
```

But I am getting that message :

```
"cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

there is nothing wrong with my dataframe so I am a little bit confused about this error messag, it dosent happen when the dataframe contain less than 1000 rows, but as soon as it becomes larger, this error occurs

Any idea ?

Thanks

*Update summary_data.info()*

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2176 entries, 0 to 2175
Data columns (total 27 columns):
chrom                                   2176 non-null object
coord                                   2176 non-null int64
ref_base                                2176 non-null object
var_base                                2176 non-null object
normal_ref_counts                       2176 non-null int64
normal_var_counts                       2176 non-null int64
VOA867-A1_S43_merged_ref_counts         2176 non-null object
VOA867-A1_S43_merged_var_counts         2176 non-null object
VOA867-A1_S43_merged_somatic_status     2176 non-null object
VOA867-E02_S73_merged_ref_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-E02_S73_merged_var_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-E02_S73_merged_somatic_status    2176 non-null object
VOA867-F03_S76_merged_ref_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F03_S76_merged_var_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F03_S76_merged_somatic_status    2176 non-null object
VOA867-F04_S75_merged_ref_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F04_S75_merged_var_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F04_S75_merged_somatic_status    2176 non-null object
VOA867-F09_S74_merged_ref_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F09_S74_merged_var_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867-F09_S74_merged_somatic_status    2176 non-null object
VOA867-T_S41_merged_ref_counts          2176 non-null object
VOA867-T_S41_merged_var_counts          2176 non-null object
VOA867-T_S41_merged_somatic_status      2176 non-null object
VOA867xeno_S18_merged_ref_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867xeno_S18_merged_var_counts        2176 non-null object
VOA867xeno_S18_merged_somatic_status    2176 non-null object
dtypes: int64(3), object(24)None
```

and here is the function that generates it

```
def get_summary_data(data, normal_sample):
    summary_data = []
    for index, normal_row in data[normal_sample].iterrows():
        out_row = {'chrom': index[0],
                   'coord': index[1],
                   'ref_base': normal_row['ref_base'],
                   'var_base': normal_row['var_base'],
                   'normal_ref_counts': normal_row['ref_counts'],
                   'normal_var_counts': normal_row['var_counts'],
                   }

        normal_variant_status = normal_row['variant_status']

        normal_depth = out_row['normal_ref_counts'] + out_row['normal_var_counts']

        if normal_depth > 0:
            normal_var_freq = out_row['normal_var_counts'] / normal_depth
        else:
            normal_var_freq = 0

        for sample in data:
            if sample == normal_sample:
                 continue

            sample_row = data[sample].ix[[index]]

            out_row['{0}_ref_counts'.format(sample)] = sample_row['ref_counts']

            out_row['{0}_var_counts'.format(sample)] = sample_row['var_counts']

            sample_variant_status = str(sample_row['variant_status'].iget(0))

            sample_somatic_status = call_somatic_status(normal_variant_status,
                                                        sample_variant_status,
                                                        normal_var_freq,
                                                        args.min_normal_germline_var_freq)

            out_row['{0}_somatic_status'.format(sample)] = sample_somatic_status

        summary_data.append(out_row)

    columns = ['chrom', 'coord', 'ref_base', 'var_base', 'normal_ref_counts', 'normal_var_counts']

    for sample in data:
        if sample == normal_sample:
            continue

        columns.append('{0}_ref_counts'.format(sample))

        columns.append('{0}_var_counts'.format(sample))

        columns.append('{0}_somatic_status'.format(sample))

    summary_data = pd.DataFrame(summary_data, columns=columns)

    return summary_data
```

count is supposed to be int but I can see it is considered as string here, probably because it was extracted from another dataframe ?

Comment: you should only have ``object`` dtypes for string-likes. How did you generate the data?

Comment: correct, but I can see counts having object dtypes which is suspicious

Comment: why are you iterating???? these are all simple vectorized calcs

Comment: Well that's not my code actually, but I am using a tool where this is implemented and it is getting me these errors, you think there is no need for the first for loop ? I think the iteration is because data contains different data[sample], think of it like an excel workbook with different sheets

Comment: I actually solved the problem by adding .iget(0) in the sample_row['values'] field, since it is returning slice not cell values

Comment: you can try convert_objects(); in general if u find that you are iterating or a frame then you are doing something wrong (except for some very special cases). check out the various pandas tutorials

Comment: Thanks Jeff for helping to figure out this

Comment: Side issue: in `constant_memory` mode XlsxWriter requires that data in written in row x column order but the Pandas Excel writer works in column x row order. So I wonder if the `constant_memory` option is actually getting passed or if the dataframe is actually being written correctly.

Comment: good point @jmcnamara, actually I removed it, the results ended up being an empty excel file, I removed the engine and the constant_memory, and added the change needed for the dtypes and now it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

.to_excel only takes columns that are type: object.  The quick way to fix this is to force all of the columns to object types before writing with:

```
summary_data = summary_data.astype(object)
```

Then you can write it without crashing:

```
summary_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='summary', na_rep='NA', index=False)
```

There is some munging to do here as in some cases I have to copy the columns over as object type. Wierd. The other option is to just drop the columns that are the problem.